# How do I merge Gerrit instances without losing history

Tags: gerrit

We have a couple Gerrit (v2.8 and v2.9) instances in our company we want to merge into one. We want to do this without losing history regarding reviews etc. Moving the git repos won't be an issue, but when it comes to the Gerrit data it might be more complicated. Any advice on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to merge the databases by hand, which will include re-indexing at least one of the databases so you don't have ID collisions.  When you change the IDs in one of the databases, you'll have to change the data in the repository to match (all the refs/changes/* identifiers, etc).  You'll need to keep the server down during this transition.  It won't be an easy or fast task.